# Can't create database with Symfony 4.1 : could not find driver

Tags: php, symfony

When i do the command **php bin/console doctrine:database:create** i have these errors :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 126:   An exception occurred in
>   driver: could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 50:   could not find driver
>
> In PDOConnection.php line 46:   could not find driver

---

config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    default_table_options:
        charset: utf8mb4
        collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/blogMyProject
```

My PHP Extensions:
[image: My PHP Extensions]

php.ini extensions:
[image: php.ini extensions]

PHP 7.2.7 - MySQL 5.7.11 - Symfony 4.1.4 - I use [UwAmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HunFM.png) 3.1.0 - I'm on Windows

I don't understand where these errors come from.

Comment: Do you have a seperate `php.ini` for the PHP CLI in UwAmp if so check that all the required extensions are activated in there as well as the `php.ini` used by your web server

Comment: Check if `php-mysql` is installed on your server

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have add my php.ini on my post. I have the extension pdo_mysql.

Comment: @Preciel i use UwAmp on Windows, not Linux.

Comment: Right: But as I said in my previous comment. Some systems have **2** `php.ini` files. One is used by the PHP under Apache and the other is used by PHP CLI (Command Line Interface) Look in the folder containing `PHP` and see if there is a `php.ini` in that folder. That will be the one used by the CLI

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand.It works ! It was necessary to modify the php.ini of the bin / php directory, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RiggsFolly brought the solution :

I have a second `php.ini` file in UwAmp. The extension `pdo_mysql` was disabled in `bin/php/php-version/php.ini`

Answer (score 6):

This works for my case

```
symfony 4.2
php 7.3
```

I enabled

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

```
in file=> config\packages\doctrine.yaml
```

---

```
dbal:
        dbname:               database
        host:                 localhost
        port:                 1234
        user:                 user
        password:             secret
        driver:               pdo_mysql
        # if the url option is specified, it will override the above config
        url:                  mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
        # the DBAL driverClass option
        driver_class:         App\DBAL\MyDatabaseDriver
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Actually, all you need is the driver and url parameters, as the url already contains user, password, host and port.

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed UwAmp 3.1.0 on a Windows 10 machine, and faced this same issue when trying to run the `php artisan migrate` command on a Laravel app. Here's how I solved it:

- Go to `bin/php/<php-version>`
- Make a copy of `php_uwamp.ini` named `php-cli.ini`
- Open it on a text editor
- Replace `extension_dir = "{PHPEXTPATH}"` by `extension_dir = "ext"`
- Replace `zend_extension = "{PHPZENDPATH}/php_xdebug.dll"` by `extension_dir = "../zend_ext/php_xdebug.dll"`

Every time you change PHP Config on UwAmp interface, you must repeat these steps, since the changes are stored on `php_uwamp.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

in the file php.ini there is the extension extension=pdo_mysql that is disabled. I enabled it and the connection worked.